# Redirect users after they reset their password

Tags: joomla-3.x, user, account-password

Is there any way to force a redirect after a user has reset their password without modifying core files?

From what I can tell, there aren't really any variables that Joomla! sends back confirming a successful reset that I can use to force a redirect. Additionally, I can't find any variables referenced in the model/controller/helper that I could set to tell Joomla! to return to a different page.

The closest I've come to finding a variable I can set to let the component know that I want to redirect was `JFactory::getApplication()->getUserState('com_users.edit.profile.redirect')`. This didn't seem to work.

Comment: I'd be looking at the onUserAfterSave hook. From the description ("This event is triggered after an update of a user record"), I think this should fire a plugin at the appropriate time.

Comment: Well, made a plugin and set up a couple of checks in `onUserAfterSave`, and sure enough I was able to catch a successful password change and redirect to a page I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: Richard B, post your comment as answer. Otherwise, this question will continue to stay in unanswered category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **onUserAfterSave** hook allows you to access this data at the appropriate time via a plugin.

Comment: (added as an answer, as per Saibbyweb's suggestion)

Comment: For anyone using this solution, be extremely careful about how to handle the redirect here. A very, VERY large amount of functions set off the `onUserAfterSave` hook. Make absolutely sure that your redirect sets off under exact/specific conditions.